# Python 3: I have the issue : ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0) in a really simple script:

Tags: python, http, request, cloud, pcloud

I want to upload a file with pcloud here is my code :

```
import requests
url = 'https://api.pcloud.com/uploadfile'
path = 'C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\Folder\\log.txt'
files = {open(path, 'rb')}
data = {'username': 'emailadress@gmail.com', 'password': 'mypassword'}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data)
print(r.text())
```

I have got the following issue:

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: Why is `files` a set?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: What line is the error on? You have more information than us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`files` should be dictionary but you created `set()` - (both uses `{}` to create instance)

```
 files = {'file': open(path, 'rb')}
```

---

**BTW:** you have to use `r.text` without `()`.

Or `r.json()` with `()` to get result as Python's dictionary.